# How can I get an integer as output for continuous action space PPO reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-neural-networks, proximal-policy-optimization, continuous-action-spaces

I have a huge discrete action space, the learning stability is not good. I'd like to move to continuous action space but the only output for my task can be a positive integer (let's say in the range 0 to 999). How can I force the DNN to output a positive integer?